# In linq, is comparing by reference or string faster?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core-2.0

I have a huge query that I'm trying to improve the performance of. The main reason why it's slow is because I'm using a lot of `Includes`.

I just noticed i'm doing a reference comparison between the two instances of my Player class:

```
Where (p => p.Player == player)
```

Here's my Player class:

```
class player
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    // other properties
}
```

Would it be faster to do `Where(p => p.Player.Id == player.Id)` instead?

Comment: What were the results when you timed the operation in your environment?

Comment: They were too close for me to tell the difference. Albeit, I was just using the times restlet was giving me when the request finishes. I didn't write a profiler. I guess I was just wondering if in general, is comparing by reference faster than string comparison.

Comment: Your linq is going to be converted to SQL statements so I strongly suspect that they will actually produce the exact same result.

Comment: If `Player` equality is based on comparing `Id` then why not simply use `Where(p => p.Player.Id == player.Id)`? Makes it clear what you're comparing.

Comment: What SQL was generated by each option?

Comment: You've written the code both ways. If you want to know which way was faster, **run it both ways and then you'll know**.  Asking random people on the internet to guess which one is faster is unlikely to get you an accurate answer. If, as you note, you can't tell the difference, then *what does it matter which one was faster?*  If you can't tell then no one else can either. Also, you say you know where the perf problem is, and that it isn't here, so why are you wasting any time looking where the problem *isn't*?

Comment: As far as i'm aware `Db.Players.Where(p => p.Player == player)`  in EF will give you a big nasty exception anyway

Comment: You should use whatever makes the most sense (which is likely `p.Player.Id`)

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat lol. I'll just use player.Id so its more clear. But  @TheGeneral, it doesn't throw an exception and works.

Comment: Why not `p => p.PlayerId == player.Id`?

Comment: If you just do `p => p.Player == player` it works without having to include player. Otherwise you can't access Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas you forgot to inform us about your context. Seeing your tag `entity-framework` I assume you want to perform the LINQ query as an `IQueryable`, and not `AsEnumerable`.

But let's assume that you want to know which code will result in the smartest SQL code when executed.

It seems that your `Player` is an entity class in a one-to-many (or many-to-many) relationship with another entity, for example `PlayedGames` Every `Player` has zero or more `PlayedGames`, every `PlayedGame` was played by exactly one `Player`

In entity framework you would design this like:

```
class Player
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // every Player has zero or more PlayedGames
    public virtual ICollection<PlayedGame> PlayedGames{get; set;}
}

class PlayedGame
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Score {get; set;}

    // every PlayedGame was played by exactly one Player using foreign key
    public int PlayerId{get; set;}
    public virtual Player Player {get; set;}
}
```

Suppose, somehow you've got a Player. There are several ways you can fetch the PlayedGames of this Player. Two of them are very similar to your code:

```
Player player1 = ...
var gamesOfPlayer = dbContext.PlayedGames
    .Where(game => game.Player == player1)
    .ToList();
```

Or you could go for:

```
var gamesOfPlayer = dbContext.PlayedGames
    .Where(game => game.Player.Id == player1.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Your queries will be more elaborate, but you get the gist.

There are several other possibilities which are more intuitive to me:

```
var gamesOfPlayer = dbContext.PlayedGames
    .Where(game => game.PlayerId == player1.Id)
    .ToList();

var gamesOfPlayer = player.PlayedGames;
```

Personally I'd go for the last solution. To me it seems the most natural to me. But lets check the SQL code that entity framework will make of this.

**Change of plan:**:
I got an exception when I tried to execute the query with `.Where(game => game.Player == player1)`. I already expected that, after all, SQL does not know when you would consider two players to be identical. I hoped that maybe entity framework was smart enough to think that the user would mean `Where the player has an Id equal to player1`.

So we'll have to skip this. Three more to go.
For the tests I used Microsoft's SQL Server Profiler. The SQL is a bit translated to make it more readable

**(1) use Player.Id**
`.Where(game => game.Player.Id == player1.Id)`
This one results in the following SQL:

exec Select
       PlayedGames.Id as Id,
       PlayedGames.Score as Score
   from dbo.PlayedGames as PlayedGames
   where playedGames.PlayerId = @constant1

Note that entity framework was smart enough to see that `Player.Id` was in fact the foreign key

**(2) Use foreign key Played.Id**
`.Where(game => game.PlayerId == player1.Id)`

```
exec Select
   PlayedGames.Id as Id,
   PlayedGames.Score as Score
```

from dbo.PlayedGames as PlayedGames
   where playedGames.PlayerId = @constant1

Because the previous one already was smart enough to use the foreign key, it is not a surprise that this code leads to the same SQL

**(3) Use the Player's property PlayedGames**
`var gamesOfPlayer = player.PlayedGames;`

```
exec Select
    PlayedGames.Id as Id,
    PlayedGames.Score as Score
from dbo.PlayedGames as PlayedGames
where playedGames.PlayerId = @constant1
```

**Entity Framework did not translate this into a Join from Players and PLayedGames!**
Entity Framework detected that I do not need any of the properties of a Player, and thus goes straight to the PlayedGames table using the foreign key again.

(Actually, as this is my preferred method, I already knew this would be the case).

**Conclusions**
 - I'm not sure whether you will be able to execute `.Where(game => game.Player == player1)`.
 - All other methods will all use the foreign key. They lead to the same SQL

Personally I'd go for the code that looks most naturally. For those with a SQL background this will be the method with the foreign key in the Where statement. For those who are thinking in collections (with a database more as an abstract thing in the background) it will be the user of `Player.PlayedGames`.

I've also tested this in code where I fetched some properties of a Player with his Played games. Again, the three Where methods lead to the same SQL statements.

### Use Select instead of Include

**Advice: only use Include if you plan to change the fetched values**

One of the slower parts of querying a database is the transport of the fetched data to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of transferred data.

If you would fetch `a player with his PlayedGames` using Include you will get all properties of the PlayedGames, inclusive the foreign key `PlayerId`, or which you already know that this value equals the fetched `Player.Id`. So if you fetch a thousand players, each player with a 20 played games, you'll transfer 20 thousand foreign keys of which you already know the value.

Apart from that, there might be other properties that you don't plan to use after the fetch.

So instead of:

```
var playersWithGames = dbContects.Players
    .Include(player => player.PlayedGames)
    .Where(player => ...)
    .ToList();
```

The following would be much more efficient in most use cases:

```
var playersWitGames = dbContext.Players
   .Where(player => ...)
   .Select(player => new
   {   // select only the properties you plan to use
       Id = player.Id,
       Name = player.Name,
       // not needed for this query: Birthday, emergency telephone number,
       // bank account, marital status

       Games = player.PlayedGames
           .Where(game => ...) // if you don't need all games
           .Select(game => new
           {
                // not sure if needed: game.Id
                // certainly not needed: game.PlayerId
                Date = game.Date,
                Score = game.Score,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
   });
```

When using the fetched results you won't see any difference between using `Include` or `Select` as long as you don't use a property that you didn't plan to use.

But then again: if you use a property you didn't plan to use you'd get a compiler error, so you'll never transfer a property *by accident*.

**Conclusion: only use Include if you plan to change the fetched item**

I hardly thank that you every plan to change a `Player with all his PlayedGames`, you'll change properties of the `Player`, or maybe properties of one of his `PlayedGames`, but seldom several of his `PlayedGames` in one go.

In my experience I seldom use `Include` in a one-to-many relation. Sometimes in a one-to-zero-or-one relation: "Change the Player with his Address", although It would normally be: "Change the player's Address"

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. I'm still quite confused about the last part. Instead of including the PlayedGames, we can use it directly in a Select clause?

Comment: Yes you can. In most use case I create an anonymous type in whic I select only the properties I plan to use. In some cases, for instance because of return values I de `new mytype` in my select statement. This requires a default  constructor and public set properties